# Foundation media queries in font-family

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

In Foundation, the main CSS file begins with this

```
meta.foundation-mq-small {
  font-family: "/only screen and (max-width: 40em)/";
  width: 0em; }

meta.foundation-mq-medium {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:40.063em) and (max-width:64em)/";
  width: 40.063em; }

meta.foundation-mq-large {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:64.063em)/";
  width: 64.063em; }

meta.foundation-mq-xlarge {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:90.063em)/";
  width: 90.063em; }

meta.foundation-mq-xxlarge {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:120.063em)/";
  width: 120.063em; }
```

Why are there media queries in the font-family property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at [foundation.js on Github](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/11945843d331c4ddce08c30593fd76a2338a1bce/js/foundation/foundation.js#L181) it looks like they are just using the font-family value to pass the media queries to Javascript, presumably to keep them consistent if people change the defaults in SCSS. In the CSS it's not going to match a valid font name and will just be safely ignored.